# Persisting "no such column error" when using ListActivity with LoaderCallbacks

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

My problem is very small but i can't seem to find a solution.Below is my code then i explain my issue.

The **MetersActivity** class

```
public class MetersActivity extends ListActivity implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.meters_list);

    this.getListView().setDividerHeight(2);

    fillData();

    registerForContextMenu(getListView());
}
private void fillData() {
    // Fields from the database (projection)
    // Must include the _id column for the adapter to work

      LoaderManager lm = getLoaderManager();

    String[] dataColumns = {"_id ", " meterNumber " };
    int[] meter = { R.id.meter_number_label};

    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.meter_row,
            null, dataColumns, meter, 0);

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    lm.initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
}
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id,
        Bundle args) {

    String[] PROJECTION = new String[] { "_id ", " meterNumber "};
    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(MetersActivity.this,UserAccountsContentProvider.CONTENT_URI,PROJECTION, null, null, null);

     return cursorLoader;

}
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {

    // A switch-case is useful when dealing with multiple Loaders/IDs
    switch (loader.getId()) {
      case LOADER_ID:
        // The asynchronous load is complete and the data
        // is now available for use. Only now can we associate
        // the queried Cursor with the SimpleCursorAdapter.
        adapter.swapCursor(data);
        break;
    }


}


@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    // data is not available anymore, delete reference
    adapter.swapCursor(null);

}
}
```

My class where i create my tables :

```
// Database creation SQL statement for meters table
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_METERS = "create table " 
        + TABLE_METERS
        + "(" 
        + METER_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
        + METER_NUMBER + " integer not null, " 
        + PLOT_NUMBER + " varchar not null, "
        + COLUMN_CATEGORY + " varchar not null "
        + ");";


// Database creation SQL statement for customers table
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_CUSTOMERS = "create table " 
        + TABLE_CUSTOMERS
        + "(" 
        + KEY_CUSTOMER_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
        + KEY_FIRST_NAME + " text, " 
        + KEY_LAST_NAME + " text, "
        + KEY_ADDRESS + " varchar, "
        + KEY_EMAIL + " varchar, "
        + KEY_PHONE_NUMBER + " integer, "
        + KEY_ACCOUNT_NUMBER + " integer, "
        + KEY_METER_ID + " integer not null, "
        + KEY_METER_NUMBER + " integer not null, "
        + KEY_PLOT_NUMBER + " varchar not null, "
        +" FOREIGN KEY ("+KEY_METER_ID+") REFERENCES "+TABLE_METERS+" ("+METER_ID+"), " 
        +" FOREIGN KEY ("+KEY_METER_NUMBER+") REFERENCES "+TABLE_METERS+" ("+METER_NUMBER+"), " 
        +" FOREIGN KEY ("+KEY_PLOT_NUMBER+") REFERENCES "+TABLE_METERS+" ("+PLOT_NUMBER+"));"
        + ");"; 


// Database creation SQL statement for water bills table

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_WATERBILL = "create table " 
        + TABLE_WATER_BILL
        + "(" 
        + BILL_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + BILL_NUMBER + " integer, "
        + KEY_BILLING_DATE + " date, " 
        + KEY_PREVIOUS_READING + " integer, "
        + KEY_CURRENT_READING+ " integer, "
        + KEY_DATEOF_READING + " date, "
        + KEY_CONSUMPTION + " integer, "
        + KEY_DUE_DATE  + " date, "
        + KEY_BILL_ITEMS + " varchar, "
        +  KEY_RATE + " integer, "
        +  KEY_CHARGES + " integer, "
        +  KEY_CONSUMPTION_PERIOD + " date, "
        +  KEY_TOTAL_DUE + " integer, "
        +  BILL_METER_ID + " integer not null, "
        + " FOREIGN KEY ("+BILL_METER_ID+") REFERENCES "+TABLE_CUSTOMERS+" ("+KEY_METER_ID+"));"
        + ");"; 


public static void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database){
database.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_METERS);
    database.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_CUSTOMERS);
    database.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_WATERBILL);
}
```

My **Logcat output**

```
03-13 10:45:29.058: E/SQLiteLog(827): (1) no such column: meterNumber
03-13 10:45:29.158: E/AndroidRuntime(827): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
03-13 10:45:29.158: E/AndroidRuntime(827): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing    doInBackground()
03-13 10:45:29.158: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
03-13 10:45:29.158: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at  java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
03-13 10:45:29.158: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
03-13 10:45:29.158: E/AndroidRuntime(827): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such  column: meterNumber (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id ,  meterNumber  FROM waterbills
03-13 10:45:29.158: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
```

**The issue**

I'm trying to retrieve data from SQLite with a ContentProvider,and display it as a list.I have a list activity which implements LoaderCallbacks.I have  checked tonnes of tutorials and even followed some to the letter but my app crashes for some reason.I have buttons on the main activity with one for displaying a list of clients.When i click the button,i'm supposed to go to a separate activity which shows me the list of names,but instead it crashes after clicking the button with the "no such column while compiling...." error.

I have three tables-customers,meters and waterbills. The column meterNumber is found in the table meters,but i noticed that the error states that the column "meterNumber" is not found in table waterbills!So i'm wondering why it's referencing that in the first place yet I've checked the code and it seems to be okay.I have also uninstalled the app severally,increased the database version but still doesn't work.Sometimes an extra set of eyes just helps to see the things we don't.I would really appreciate some help.

**Edit with content provider class**

```
public class UserAccountsContentProvider extends ContentProvider{
private DatabaseHandler database;

    // Used for the UriMacher
    private static final int all_meters = 10;
    private static final int single_meter = 20;

    private static final int all_customers = 30;
    private static final int single_customer = 40;

    private static final int all_bills = 50;
    private static final int single_bill = 60;


    private static final String AUTHORITY = "com.isys.waterbillingsystem.contentprovider";



    //table meters

    private static final String METER_PATH = "meters";

    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_METER = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY
            + "/" + METER_PATH);

    public static final String CONTENT_METER_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE
              + "/meters";
    public static final String CONTENT_ITEM_METER_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_ITEM_BASE_TYPE
              + "/meter";

    //table customers

    private static final String CUSTOMERS_PATH = "customers";

    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_CUSTOMERS = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY
            + "/" + CUSTOMERS_PATH);

    public static final String CONTENT_CUSTOMER_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE
              + "/customers";
    public static final String CONTENT_ITEM_CUSTOMER_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_ITEM_BASE_TYPE
              + "/customer";

    //table waterbills

    private static final String BILL_PATH = "bills";

    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_WATERBILLS = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY
            + "/" + BILL_PATH);



    private static final UriMatcher sURIMatcher = new UriMatcher(
            UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    static {
        sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, METER_PATH, all_meters);
        sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, METER_PATH + "/#", single_meter);

        sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, CUSTOMERS_PATH, all_customers);
        sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, CUSTOMERS_PATH + "/#", single_customer);

        sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BILL_PATH, all_bills);
        sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BILL_PATH + "/#", single_bill);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        try {

            database = new DatabaseHandler(getContext());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = database.getWritableDatabase();

        // Using SQLiteQueryBuilder instead of query() method
        SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

        queryBuilder.setTables(MeterTableDetails.TABLE_METERS);

        queryBuilder.setTables(CustomerTableDetails.TABLE_CUSTOMERS);

        queryBuilder.setTables(WaterBillTableDetails.TABLE_WATER_BILL);


        int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
        switch (uriType) {
        case all_meters:
            break;
        case single_meter:
            // Adding the ID to the original query

            String id = uri.getPathSegments().get(1);
            queryBuilder.appendWhere(MeterTableDetails.METER_ID + "=" + id);

            break;

        case all_customers:
            break;
        case single_customer:
            // Adding the ID to the original query
            String id1 = uri.getPathSegments().get(1);
            queryBuilder.appendWhere(CustomerTableDetails.KEY_CUSTOMER_ID + "=" + id1);
            break;

        case all_bills:
            break;
        case single_bill:
            // Adding the ID to the original query
            String id2 = uri.getPathSegments().get(1);
            queryBuilder.appendWhere(WaterBillTableDetails.BILL_ID + "=" + id2);
            break;

        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
        }

        Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(db, projection, selection,
                selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
        // Make sure that potential listeners are getting notified
        cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);

        return cursor;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
        SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = database.getWritableDatabase();

        long id = 0;

        switch (uriType) {
        case all_meters:
            id = sqlDB.insert(MeterTableDetails.TABLE_METERS, null, values);

            break;

        case all_customers:

            id = sqlDB.insert(CustomerTableDetails.TABLE_CUSTOMERS, null, values);

            break;

        case all_bills:

            id = sqlDB.insert(WaterBillTableDetails.TABLE_WATER_BILL, null, values);

            break;


        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
        }
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        return Uri.parse(METER_PATH + "/" + id);
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
        SQLiteDatabase db = database.getWritableDatabase();

        switch (uriType) {
        case all_meters:
            break;
        case single_meter:

            String id = uri.getPathSegments().get(1);
            selection = MeterTableDetails.METER_ID
                    + "="
                    + id
                    + (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection) ? " AND (" + selection
                            + ')' : "");

            break;

        case all_customers:
            break;
        case single_customer:

            String id1 = uri.getPathSegments().get(1);
            selection = CustomerTableDetails.KEY_CUSTOMER_ID
                    + "="
                    + id1
                    + (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection) ? " AND (" + selection
                            + ')' : "");
            break;

        case all_bills:
            break;
        case single_bill:

            String id2 = uri.getPathSegments().get(1);
            selection = WaterBillTableDetails.BILL_ID
                    + "="
                    + id2
                    + (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection) ? " AND (" + selection
                            + ')' : "");
            break;


        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
        }

        int deleteCount;
        deleteCount = db.delete(MeterTableDetails.TABLE_METERS, selection,
                selectionArgs);

        deleteCount = db.delete(CustomerTableDetails.TABLE_CUSTOMERS, selection,
                selectionArgs);

         deleteCount = db.delete(WaterBillTableDetails.TABLE_WATER_BILL, selection,
         selectionArgs);


        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);

        return deleteCount;
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs) {

        int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
        SQLiteDatabase db = database.getWritableDatabase();

        switch (uriType) {
        case all_meters:

            break;
        case single_meter:

            String id = uri.getPathSegments().get(1);
            selection = MeterTableDetails.METER_ID
                    + "="
                    + id
                    + (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection) ? " AND (" + selection
                            + ')' : "");

            break;

        case all_customers:

            break;
        case single_customer:

            String id1 = uri.getPathSegments().get(1);
            selection = CustomerTableDetails.KEY_CUSTOMER_ID
                    + "="
                    + id1
                    + (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection) ? " AND (" + selection
                            + ')' : "");

            break;

        case all_bills:

            break;
        case single_bill:

            String id2 = uri.getPathSegments().get(1);
            selection = WaterBillTableDetails.BILL_ID
                    + "="
                    + id2
                    + (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection) ? " AND (" + selection
                            + ')' : "");

            break;

        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
        }

        int updateCount;

        updateCount = db.update(MeterTableDetails.TABLE_METERS, values,
                selection, selectionArgs);
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);

        updateCount = db.update(CustomerTableDetails.TABLE_CUSTOMERS, values, selection,
                selectionArgs);
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);

         updateCount = db.update(WaterBillTableDetails.TABLE_WATER_BILL, values, selection,
         selectionArgs);



        return updateCount;
    }


}
```

Comment: why do you have spaces around your column names ?

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, it appears you've got something mixed up in your Content Provider. Please post the relevant code from that class.

Comment: @pskink because from other people on this site who had a similar 'no such column' issue,some were advised to create spaces after the comma,so that the query doesn't interpret it as one word after the plus sign..so i decided to try that also..but clearly it's not solving my problem..

Comment: @MikeM. i just added my content provider class...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have no `MeterNumber` column in table `waterbills`:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_WATERBILL = "create table " 

+ TABLE_WATER_BILL
+ "(" 
+ BILL_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
+ BILL_NUMBER + " integer, "
+ KEY_BILLING_DATE + " date, " 
+ KEY_PREVIOUS_READING + " integer, "
+ KEY_CURRENT_READING+ " integer, "
+ KEY_DATEOF_READING + " date, "
+ KEY_CONSUMPTION + " integer, "
+ KEY_DUE_DATE  + " date, "
+ KEY_BILL_ITEMS + " varchar, "
+  KEY_RATE + " integer, "
+  KEY_CHARGES + " integer, "
+  KEY_CONSUMPTION_PERIOD + " date, "
+  KEY_TOTAL_DUE + " integer, "
+  BILL_METER_ID + " integer not null, "
+ " FOREIGN KEY ("+BILL_METER_ID+") REFERENCES "+TABLE_CUSTOMERS+" ("+KEY_METER_ID+"));"
+ ");";
```

What are you waiting from the query?

In your data provider you set tables, which will used in query like that:

```
 queryBuilder.setTables(MeterTableDetails.TABLE_METERS);

 queryBuilder.setTables(CustomerTableDetails.TABLE_CUSTOMERS);

 queryBuilder.setTables(WaterBillTableDetails.TABLE_WATER_BILL);
```

It's wrong. Query will be excecuted only on WATER_BILL table. If you want to get data from many tables [use JOIN](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html#setTables%28java.lang.String%29) :

```
queryBuilder.setTables(MeterTableDetails.TABLE_METERS INNER JOIN CustomerTableDetails.TABLE_CUSTOMERS ON (....));
```

Comment: Hey @MikkanRin no i don't have that column in water bills table..The query is supposed to give me a list of all the numbers of the meters registered in the meters table..that's why in onCreate Loader i enter the "_id" and "meterNumber " columns...

Comment: So why you use waterbills table to get MeterNumbers? `03-13 10:45:29.158: E/AndroidRuntime(827): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such  column: meterNumber (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id ,  meterNumber  FROM waterbills`

Comment: I am not..that's the problem..or atleast if i am..then i can't seem to find where exactly in my code i have used waterbills to get meterNumber..can you spot where i do that in my code?...

Comment: i just added my content provider class also..and it seems okay to me..so i don't know where i am referencing the waterbills table instead of the meters table..

Comment: Wow thank you..so much @MIkkaRin i'm gonna do that right away and give you the feed back..so because i have three tables here,will i have two joins in one like this : queryBuilder.setTables(MeterTableDetails.TABLE_METERS INNER JOIN CustomerTableDetails.TABLE_CUSTOMERS ON (MeterTableDetails.METER_ID = CustomerTableDetails.KEY_METER_ID));

Comment: Yes, you need two joins. I don't know exactly relations between your tables, so as template it must look like this: `queryBuilder.setTables(tableA INNER JOIN TableB on (A_id=B_id) INNER JOIN TableC on (C_id=B_id));` Of course you may use LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and so on, deepends of what you want to get

Comment: so this is my new querybuilder statement:                  queryBuilder.setTables(MeterTableDetails.TABLE_METERS + " INNER JOIN " + CustomerTableDetails.TABLE_CUSTOMERS + " ON "+ (MeterTableDetails.METER_ID = CustomerTableDetails.KEY_METER_ID) +" INNER JOIN "+ WaterBillTableDetails.TABLE_WATER_BILL +" ON "+(CustomerTableDetails.KEY_METER_ID = WaterBillTableDetails.BILL_METER_ID));

Comment: But i get this error in Logcat                                     03-13 15:33:53.195: E/SQLiteLog(850): (1) ambiguous column name: _id
03-13 15:33:53.285: E/AndroidRuntime(850): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: ambiguous column name: _id (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id ,  meterNumber  FROM meters INNER JOIN customers ON meterId INNER JOIN waterbills ON meterId

Comment: the relationship is such that each customer is assigned a meter hence the KEY_METER_ID column is a foreign key in customers table.Then each customer has a waterbill statement so their assigned meter_id appears on their bill..that's why the BILL_METER_ID references the KEY_METER_ID on the customer's table.

Comment: ambiguous column - is mean column with this name exists in more than one table, so to call it in query you should specify name of table from which get a column  - `TableA.A_id`

Comment: I have edited my onCreateLoader like this :                    String[] PROJECTION = new String[] { MeterTableDetails.METER_ID +" AS _id", MeterTableDetails.METER_NUMBER};                        following your advice but i still get the ambiguous column error.. do i also need to edit the querybuilder statement?

Comment: Did you change this one? `String[] dataColumns = {"_id ", " meterNumber " };`

Comment: The setTables querybuilder now looks like this:                        queryBuilder.setTables(MeterTableDetails.TABLE_METERS+" as meters " + " INNER JOIN " + CustomerTableDetails.TABLE_CUSTOMERS+" as customers " + " ON "+ (MeterTableDetails.METER_ID = CustomerTableDetails.KEY_METER_ID) +" INNER JOIN "+ WaterBillTableDetails.TABLE_WATER_BILL+ " as waterbills " +" ON "+(CustomerTableDetails.KEY_METER_ID = WaterBillTableDetails.BILL_METER_ID));

Comment: yes, i changed that one, and it now looks like this :                 String[] dataColumns = {MeterTableDetails.METER_ID + " AS _id", MeterTableDetails.METER_NUMBER};

Comment: here's the logcat error:                                                 03-13 16:49:33.368: E/SQLiteLog(1450): (1) ambiguous column name: _id
03-13 16:49:33.686: E/AndroidRuntime(1450): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: ambiguous column name: _id (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id AS _id, meterNumber FROM meters as meters  INNER JOIN customers as customers  ON customerMeterId INNER JOIN waterbills as waterbills  ON billMeterId
03-13 16:49:33.686: E/AndroidRuntime(1450):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)

Comment: try `String[] dataColumns = {MeterTableDetails.TABLE_METERS+"."+MeterTableDetails.METER_ID + " AS _id", MeterTableDetails.METER_NUMBER};` The same with PROJECTION

Comment: oh my goodness..now it's another error on logcat:                                              03-13 17:30:56.076: E/SQLiteCursor(1575): requesting column name with table name -- meters._id AS _id
03-13 17:30:56.076: E/SQLiteCursor(1575): java.lang.Exception
03-13 17:30:56.076: E/SQLiteCursor(1575):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteCursor.java:180)
03-13 17:30:56.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1575): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-13 17:30:56.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1575): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'meters._id AS _id' does not exist

Comment: OMG...Probably you no need to use AS in DataColumns `String[] dataColumns = {MeterTableDetails.TABLE_METERS+"."+MeterTableDetails.METER_ID, MeterTableDetails.METER_NUMBER};`

Comment: OMG !! it works! finally it works..thank you so much @MikkaRin you are officially the most patient person i know.you have saved me :-) unfortunately my reputation is still less than 15 so i can't accept your answer..but i accept this as correct!!